# How to create shortcut or hotkey to quickly switch display settings for 3 external monitors from extended to mirrored for screens 2 and 3?

Tags: multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, display-settings

I am an Air Force recruiter using a Windows 10 computer with 3 external monitors connected.  Monitors 1 and 2 are primarily for my use and Monitor 3 is set up for an applicant to view.  Typically, Monitor 3 is used to display a slide show or videos while going through an interview process.  However, when it's time to start completing paperwork, I like to mirror screens 2 and 3 so we can both see the forms they will be signing.  I would like a quick way to switch from extended to mirror for screens 2 & 3.  When going through display settings, it constantly changes the order of the monitors and is just a hassle to use.  The windows+P shortcut works for extended, but doesn't work for the other setting.

Comment: See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4608-create-display-switch-shortcut-windows-10-a.html How to Create a Display Switch shortcut in Windows 10